# Turn off notifications for old unread emails and only keep for new emails in gmail

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, gmail

I'm using Gmail on Android 6.0 and almost every time gmail fetch new emails I have notification about old unread emails, each time I got new email the number get bigger (40 right now on my not gmail email that I've got spam sent).

I don't want to click on each email to maker it as read.

Is there a way to turn off notifications for old unread emails and only keep the ones that are for new emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed , the solution that worked is posted below

You can try [automation](/questions/tagged/automation).  I prefer [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), being easy to learn and free (upto 5 macros)

Create a macro

**Trigger:** Notification → Notification received  → Select Application  → Gmail  → Text content contains  → Enter here the text you see on the unread notifications

**Actions:**

1. Clear Notifications  → Clear all
2. *Optional if you don't want notification sound* Volume Change  → Set notification on slider scale to zero

**Constraints​ :** Leave blank